# Why does Perl complain "Useless use of a constant in void context", but only sometimes?

Tags: perl, constants, void

Here is my Perl script and its output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

(undef, 1); # no output
(0, 1);     # no output
(1, 1);     # no output
(2, 1);     # "Useless use of a constant in void context at C:\...\void.pl line 7"
(3, 1);     # "Useless use of a constant in void context at C:\...\void.pl line 8"
("", 1);    # "Useless use of a constant in void context at C:\...\void.pl line 9"
("0", 1);   # "Useless use of a constant in void context at C:\...\void.pl line 10"
("1", 1);   # "Useless use of a constant in void context at C:\...\void.pl line 11"
```

I would expect warnings at every line. What is special about `undef`, `0` and `1` which causes this not to happen?

Answer (score 13):

Documented in [`perldoc perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Useless-use-of-%25s-in-void-context) complete with rationale:

> This warning will not be issued for numerical constants equal to `0` or `1` since they are often used in statements like
>
> ```
> 1 while sub_with_side_effects();
> ```

As for `undef`, it's a function that has uses even in void context. e.g. `undef($x)` does something similar to —but different than— `$x = undef();`. (You normally want the latter.) A warning could be issued for uses of `undef` without args in void context, but it would require specialized code, and it's simply not needed.

Comment: I was just going to say this too. It says under `Useless use of %s in void context` that `This warning will not be issued for numerical constants equal to 0 or 1` http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Useless-use-of-%s-in-void-context

Comment: Nice digging through the docs. Doesn't explain `(undef, 1)`, though. (Is throwing away `undef` considered not throwing away anything?)

Comment: @Ted Hopp, I've added an explanation for `undef`.